# Fill fieldX based on shared fieldY

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro

I have a dataset with sensors measuring e.g. Nitrogen. Every sensor has an unique `ID`, but for every sensor there are multiple points (for each year one). However, when adding the new values for this year not all fields are filled resulting in the following schema:

```
  ID        Year       Location description
SensorA     2020       
SensorA     2019       UndertheBridge
```

What I want to establish is that location description for 2020 is filled with the one of 2019, if 2019 is filled. How could I best establish that? My attempts so far in the field calculator have not the desired result.

Comment: What code have you tried in the field calculator?  When you ran it did you get an error message?

Comment: You need to give a better example of the range of data you have. You say you have  a sensor for every year but only show 2 years, can sensorX exist in 3 or 4 years?. If you only have 2 years, as shown in your example, then the year is irrelevant SensorA is always "UndertheBridge".